# GitLab-runner test execution

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have built GitLab-runner on a non-Intel architecture using the reference https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/development/. Is there any way to execute core tests only rather than executing all core+executor tests which requires installation of multiple dependencies. Please let me know if I need to connect runner to GitLab instance to execute test cases.